# Kendo hierarchical Grid, open first opened detailgrid in group

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, hierarchical

In my example, http://dojo.telerik.com/UVoSUl/11 I would like to open the first open row. In this example, Group B, Company 5.
I would like to expand Company 5 with expandRow().
Your help would be very happy.

Comment: one solution is, to sorting the groups. The open groups in the top an then open the first tr: this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());. But Groups are not sortable in Kendo: Look at thes thread: [Custom sorting for group](http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-sorting-for-group) - No Solution with Group-Sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the example, Company 5 is the first row with class of k-master-row that is visible. So you could use the jQuery :visible selector to get the row and then expand it:

```
this.expandRow($("tr.k-master-row:visible").eq(0));
```

Updated **[DOJO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uQeCU)**

Comment: Working solution sample: [http://dojo.telerik.com/UVoSUl/13](http://dojo.telerik.com/UVoSUl/13)